# rails 4 users reviews for users how to do this

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

i want create reviews for users from users, how better create db and Active Record Associations, i am thinking of create model reviews, reviews table with content string and table users_users with 2 strings user_id, user_id, first string who create review and second for whom created review, or this wrong way?

Comment: _i want create reviews for users from users_ - can you explain this?

Comment: users can write review for another user...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your question is very vague, I'm guessing you're quite new to Rails, so I thought I'd write this post for you

---

**User has_many Reviews**

Sounds to me like you need help with [`ActiveRecord associations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), which will allow you to create Reviews from Users

Specifically, you'd want to use the [`has_many` relationship](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association), so that a `user has_many reviews`:

[image: has_many relationship]

You'd set up 2 models like this:

```
#app/models/review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :reviews
end
```

This will allow you to call the User's ActiveRecord objects like this:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def index
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   @reviews = @user.reviews
end
```

---

**Saving Reviews to Users**

Having this setup will allow you to save reviews to specific users

To do this, you'll be able to either use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) or in the `reviews` controller, you can merge the `user_id` of the current user to assign a value to the "foreign key" (`user_id`) column ActiveRecord uses in its association

The latter is the most straightforward to explain, so I'll give you a demo:

```
#app/controllers/reviews_controller.rb
def new
    @review = Review.new
end

def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.save
end

private
def review_params
    params.require(:review).permit(:title, :body).merge(:user_id => current_user.id)
end


#app/views/reviews/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @review do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :body %>
<% end %>
```

This will save the review you post with an attached `user_id`, which you can then call with something like `@user.reviews`

Hope this helps?

Comment: how to show who write review?

Comment: its works, but i dont know how to show who write the review

Comment: Hey buddy! Sorry about the lack of reply. If you want to show the original reviewer's details, you'll need another column in your `reviews` database called `reviewer_id`. You can then put this association in your `review.rb` file: `has_one :reviewer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'reviewer_id'`. This will allow you to call `@user.review.reviewer.email` for any user, if you put data into `reviwer_id` of course

Comment: great its works) magic) but i have questions when i puts @user.reviews rails show me <ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Review:0x3823278> i need create feed to the correctly showing reviews?

Comment: That error is because `@user.reviews` is a collection of reviews for that user. To display them individually, you can either use the [`.first`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first) function, or cycle through them with `@user.reviews.each do |review|`

Comment: Hey -did you need to make 'reviewer' belong to review for the review name to be displayed?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can limit this to one new model `UserReview`, something like:

```
rails g model UserReview for_user:references by_user:references content:text stars:integer
```

And the model definition with two scopes:

```
def UserReview
  belongs_to :for_user, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :by_user, class_name: 'User'

  scope :reviews_for, ->(user) { where("for_user = ?", user) }
  scope :reviews_by,  ->(user) { where("by_user = ?", user) }
end
```

The scope methods allow for easier querying of reviews like:

```
user_reviews = UserReview.reviews_for(current_user)
```

Comment: i dont understand how to build controller with views :(

Comment: If you don't understand that, read the [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running) again.