# Rails 4 - User feedback on other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067018/rails-4-users-reviews-for-users-how-to-do-this) and I want to figure out how to show the reviewer's name on the feedback. The comment beneath the answer says to make reviewer_id belong to review. Does that mean that review has to have a has_one in the review model? I don't have a model called reviewer, so its confusing about what this suggestion means.

Comment: I think that You need to read about Self-Referential Association. See: http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association

Comment: Could you add the source of the models to better demonstrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi psantos- yes I've read it, BUT no - that doesn't help. You can see from the answer in the post Im trying to understand that reviewer is not a model. It's an attribute in the review table.

Comment: Hi Constant Meiring, i'm using the same setup as is set out in the answer I'm trying to follow.

Answer (score -1):

So you had those two models:

```
#app/models/review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end
```

Now you need to add reviewer into the review. As it was already mentioned, you need to add `reviewer_id` column and modify model accordingly:

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'reviewer_id'
end
```

you can also select reviews, which were reviewed by given user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  has_many :reviewed, class_name: 'Review', foreign_key: 'reviewer_id'
end
```

Comment: Hi dimakura - no, user receives the review. The review is provided by another user. The comment on the first answer suggests idenifying the reviewer by adding another attribute to the review model called reviewer_id.

Comment: Which model are you suggesting that I modify accordingly? I don't have a 'reviewer' model. I have a user model and a review model.

Comment: @user2860931 I assume reviewer is a user. Is it true?

Comment: I'm afraid, we're not on the same page. I can't understand what you're suggesting or asking. Reviewer id is an attribute in the review model. I don't have a reviewer model. I want to store a user id in reviewer_id so that I can post the reviewer's name beneath the review left for the other user.

Comment: @user2860931 i'm suggesting the same. If you have `review` you can now assign `review.reviewer = user2`

Comment: what do you mean if i have review? do you mean a review model? I'm sorry, I just don't understand what I need to do with this suggestion. Thanks anyway for trying.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89676/discussion-between-dimakura-and-user2860931).