# Rails: Feedback by users on other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

I'm using Rails 4 and am having trouble figuring out how to set up my models so that one user can leave feedback for another user.

I have tried to follow the answer to the attached question: [rails 4 users reviews for users how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20067018/rails-4-users-reviews-for-users-how-to-do-this)

My models are: User, Profile, Feedback

The associations between models are:

```
User.rb
has_one :profile
has_many :feedbacks
accepts_nested_attributes_for :feedbacks

Profile.rb: belongs_to :user

Feedback.rb: 
belongs_to :user
  has_one :reviewer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'reviewer'
```

The feedback table has attributes called :comment (text), :reviewer (integer) and :created_at(datetime). The reviewer needs to be the user id of the user who left the feedback.

The user model has attributes for :first_name and :last_name.

In my profile show page, I have a link to the feedback partial:

```
<%= render "feedbacks/feed" %>
```

That partial then has:

```
<div class="containerfluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

      <% if can? :read, @feedback && @user.feedback.comment.!blank %>
       <%= @profile.user.feedbacks.each do |feedback|%>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

                <%= @feedback.comment %>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="logobox">
                <%= "#{@user.feedback.reviewer.first_name} #{@user.feedback.reviewer.last_name}" %>

                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="logobox">
                <%= @feedback.try(:created_at).try(:strftime, '%d %B %Y') %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            <%= render html: "No feedback available".html_safe %>   
        </div>

      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want from the above is to display the feedback to any user who can read the feedback on the user's (receiving the feedback) profile page. If there is no feedback or the current_user cannot view the feedback, then the else statement should be applied.

I have several problems with the above:

1. I don't know how to traverse models to link to the feedback. The feedback partial is being displayed in the profile show page. Feedback belongs to user and profile belongs to user.
2. I am getting an error pointing to the first line of the above (being  <% if can? :read, @feedback && user.feedback.comment.!blank? %>. The error says it is expecting 'then'. I have never used 'then' before and it doesn't work when i just type that after blank.
3. I have an integer attribute in my feedbacks table called :reviewer. I want to store the user id of the user who created the feedback (on the other user) in that field. I don't know how to do this. The SO post copied above suggests I put a line in my feedback model which says:   has_one :reviewer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'reviewer'. I've tried this but I can't understand what it is doing.

Can anyone help? Perhaps there is another way to approach this problem and I would appreciate help finding it. The SO post I did manage to find was voted too broad, but I can't find any other references with more specific aspects of this problem set out.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would have been using polymorphic associations. Create a polymorphic model.

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :reviewer, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :reviewable, polymorphic: true
end
```

After my polymorphic model is set up I create the concerns which you can include as behaviours in your user model.

```
module Reviewer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :given_reviews, as: :reviewer, dependent: :destroy
  end
end

module Reviewable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :received_reviews, as: :reviewable, dependent: :destroy
  end
end
```

Your user model should look something like this.

```
class User
  include Reviewer #user is behaving as a reviewer
  include Reviewable #user is behaving as a reviewable entity
end
```

After all this is set up you have a reusable module to start with which will work with any other model as well.

```
userA.given_reviews #reviews posted by the user A
userA.received_reviews #reviews other people have given about user A
```

Comment: Thanks - ill give it a try and let you know

Answer (score 0):

The feedback class is a join from user-reviewer.  It should have two foreign keys on it.  For user and reviewer.  Make them both belongs_to.

```
User.rb
  has_one :profile
  has_many :feedbacks
  has_many :reviewers, :through => :feedbacks, :class_name => 'User'
  has_many :created_feedbacks, :class_name => 'Feedback', :foreign_key => 'reviewer_id'
  has_many :reviewed_users, :through => :feedbacks_left, :source => :user, :class_name => 'User'
  # Not sure if you need accepts nested attributes.

Feedback.rb: 
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :reviewer, :class_name => 'User' # foreign_key should be reviewer_id
```

Note - if you use has_one or has_many, it expects the foreign key to be on the associating class.  In the way you have it written up, that would mean the feedback_id is on the user, but that doesn't make sense.  Make it a belongs_to instead.

Change reviewer to reviewer_id and add it to the feedback model.  Then the reviewer method generated by the database column won't clobbered by the reviewer method that comes from the belongs_to.

After that, you'll be good.

Comment: Hi swards -  i dont understand. I don't have a reviewer model. its just an attribute in my feedback table. i have user_id in the feedback table, but that references the user receiving the feedback. That's why feedback belongs to user (as in the user who receives the feedback)

Comment: Right - they needed the class_name attribute to identify the class.  Typo on my part.  We are referring to it as a reviewer, but it's really just a user.

Comment: So reviewer_id in the feedback model will be allocated user id because the model association for reviewer points to user model? Thanks very much for the help

Comment: Hey - I'm trying to see whether this works, but I'm still getting this error? Some posts say that it means I'm missing an <% end %> or I have one too many. syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n'
...& @user.feedback.comment.!blank

Comment: Actually I fixed that by replacing && with and (i thought those were interchangeable). But now I get this error: undefined method `feedback' for nil:NilClass